# Как типизировать функцию?

Tags: pascal

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется

```
type TFunc=function (n:byte; i:longint):byte;
function a1(n:byte; i:longint):byte;
begin end;
```

Дальше объявлено +100500 функций с такой же записью... Хочется сделать один "шаблон" и не переписывать для каждой функции один и тот же прототип. Можно ли? Или может можно как-то по другому убрать данную повторяющуюся строчку?

Comment: эээ... а реализацию функций вы тоже хотите убрать в шаблон?

Comment: over9000 реализаций? попахивает ручным созданием массивов с заведением переменных a1, a2, a3 .. an вместо массива.

Comment: Ну хочется ему. Только вот язык для таких упражнений мягко говоря неподходящий. Такая хрень -- либо для языков с функциональными средствами, либо свидетельство сдвига по фазе.

Comment: Может человек делает то, что по факту должен делать генератор кода какой-нибудь.

Comment: @alexlz: ...либо руками написать генератор исходного кода :) на том же Delphi.

Comment: Ну реализацию в шаблон - это, конечно, здорово :D
На самом деле всё проще... Ну over9000 это, конечно, не совсем так...
20 функций на самом деле. Они считают функции тригонометрические и всякие другие... :D И вот стало интересно, можно ли убрать один и тот же кусок кода, чтобы глаза не мозолил... Так понимаю Pascal такого извращения не поддерживает?

Comment: пробовали сделать длл, запихнуть в нее все ваши математические функции, и вызывать их оттуда в коде?

Comment: Можно и так, конечно, и dll... Но когда я буду писать dll там будут всё те же заголовки для каждой функции свои =) А хочется один раз объявить прототип и сказать, что вот эти все функции будут обладать таким прототипом...

Comment: Прекрати насиловать труп. Используй современные языки, поддерживающие шаблоны/дженерики.

Comment: Не помогут тут шаблоны/дженерики. Так или иначе придется писать однотипные строки. А в случае с шаблонами может даже  больше.

Comment: @KoVadim значит надо использовать языки с автоматическим выведением типов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Придумал как сделать что-то подобное =)

```
{$MACRO ON}
{$DEFINE __func:=(x:extended):extended}

function f __func;
begin
end;
```